# R - Problems when using pivot_longer function from wide to long dataframes

Tags: r

I have some data with the following features: `id, group, sex, datebirth, date1, date2, date3, ctrl1, ctrl2, ctrl3, ab4v1, ab4v2, ab4v3`.

What I want is to transform this dataframe onto another one with the following columns in long format: `id, group, sex, datebirth, version, date, ctrl, ab4`.

(NOTE: `version` will get values 1, 2 or 3).

Usually, I would use reshape function in R, but I have to use `pivot_longer`. How could I do this transformation?

I tried things like:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c("id","group","sex","datebirth"), 
                    names_to = c("version",".value"), 
                    names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)")
```

But I get nothing... Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

This is what I have:

```
  id group    sex  datebirth    date1      date2      date3     ctrl1 ctrl2 ctrl3 ab4v1 ab4v2 ab4v3
1  1     A   Male 1975-01-08 2010-10-10 2011-11-12 2011-12-12   183   835   139   745   584   817
2  2     B   Male 1998-05-12 2010-10-10 2011-11-12 2011-12-12   172   727   214   793   653   499
3  3     A   Male 2005-12-28 2010-10-10 2011-11-23 2011-12-23   157   667   222   664   505   924
4  4     C Female 1957-07-01 2010-10-10 2011-11-25 2011-12-25   186   123   344   584   582   653
```

This is what I want:

```
      id group   sex    datebirth   version      date      ctrl   ab4   
1     1    A    Male    1975-01-08     1      2010-10-10   183    745  
2     2    B    Male    1998-05-12     1      2010-10-10   172    793  
3     3    A    Male    2005-12-28     1      2010-10-10   157    664 
4     4    C   Female   1957-07-01     1      2010-10-10   186    584  
.........
```

Comment: R is case sensitive, first you have `Group`, `Sex` and `DateBirth` then you have them all lowercase. How are they written? And you don't have a `values_to` column in `pivot_longer`.

Comment: You are right, all variables are lowercase. It was a mistake when writting the post. And about ```values_to```, I don't know how to put when I have a case like that.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of `df` and your expected output. Run `dput(head(df))` to generate a sample of `df`.

Comment: I included an example, it will be easier this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the change the order of `names_to`.  We could either use `names_sep` or `names_pattern`.  The only difference is that `names_sep` directs to a delimiter.  Here the delimiter is the boundary between a letter (`(?<=[A-Za-z])`) and a digit (`(?=[0-9]$)`).  Here, it means check for the boundary that succeeds a letter and precedes a digit.  With the `names_pattern`, we are capturing specific sets of characters in a group (`(...)`).  The OP's post used that `"([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)"` i.e. one or more letters as the first group and digits as the second group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = date1:ab4v3, names_to = c(".value", "version"), 
         names_sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9]$)")
# A tibble: 12 x 8
#      id group sex    datebirth  version date        ctrl  ab4v
#   <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <int> <int>
# 1     1 A     Male   1975-01-08 1       2010-10-10   183   745
# 2     1 A     Male   1975-01-08 2       2011-11-12   835   584
# 3     1 A     Male   1975-01-08 3       2011-12-12   139   817
# 4     2 B     Male   1998-05-12 1       2010-10-10   172   793
# 5     2 B     Male   1998-05-12 2       2011-11-12   727   653
# 6     2 B     Male   1998-05-12 3       2011-12-12   214   499
# 7     3 A     Male   2005-12-28 1       2010-10-10   157   664
# 8     3 A     Male   2005-12-28 2       2011-11-23   667   505
# 9     3 A     Male   2005-12-28 3       2011-12-23   222   924
#10     4 C     Female 1957-07-01 1       2010-10-10   186   584
#11     4 C     Female 1957-07-01 2       2011-11-25   123   582
#12     4 C     Female 1957-07-01 3       2011-12-25   344   653
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, group = c("A", "B", "A", "C"), sex = c("Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female"), datebirth = c("1975-01-08", "1998-05-12", 
"2005-12-28", "1957-07-01"), date1 = c("2010-10-10", "2010-10-10", 
"2010-10-10", "2010-10-10"), date2 = c("2011-11-12", "2011-11-12", 
"2011-11-23", "2011-11-25"), date3 = c("2011-12-12", "2011-12-12", 
"2011-12-23", "2011-12-25"), ctrl1 = c(183L, 172L, 157L, 186L
), ctrl2 = c(835L, 727L, 667L, 123L), ctrl3 = c(139L, 214L, 222L, 
344L), ab4v1 = c(745L, 793L, 664L, 584L), ab4v2 = c(584L, 653L, 
505L, 582L), ab4v3 = c(817L, 499L, 924L, 653L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That's perfect! :) Could you explain me why you use those attributes of `names_to` and `names_sep`?

Comment: @esklus thanks, added the explanation.  The `names_to` represents the components of the column.  Here, the value part belongs to the fixed component followed by the version i.e. digits part in the column name.  The `.value` is the value of those columns

Answer (score 1):

The following is ugly but I believe it might work. It's a sequence of `pivot_longer` statements, taking care of one variable in wide format at a time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fun <- function(X, Var){
  Vard <- paste0(Var, "\\d")
  X %>%
    select(1:4, matches( {{ Vard }} )) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols = matches( {{ Vard }} ),
      names_to = "version",
      values_to = Var
    ) %>%
    mutate(version = sub(Var, "", version))
}

vars <- c("date", "ctrl", "ab4v")

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), lapply(vars, function(v) fun(df1, v)))
#   id group    sex  datebirth version       date ctrl ab4v
#1   1     A   Male 1975-01-08       1 2010-10-10  183  745
#2   1     A   Male 1975-01-08       2 2011-11-12  835  584
#3   1     A   Male 1975-01-08       3 2011-12-12  139  817
#4   2     B   Male 1998-05-12       1 2010-10-10  172  793
#5   2     B   Male 1998-05-12       2 2011-11-12  727  653
#6   2     B   Male 1998-05-12       3 2011-12-12  214  499
#7   3     A   Male 2005-12-28       1 2010-10-10  157  664
#8   3     A   Male 2005-12-28       2 2011-11-23  667  505
#9   3     A   Male 2005-12-28       3 2011-12-23  222  924
#10  4     C Female 1957-07-01       1 2010-10-10  186  584
#11  4     C Female 1957-07-01       2 2011-11-25  123  582
#12  4     C Female 1957-07-01       3 2011-12-25  344  653
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I included an example of what I expect, if it helps :)